# how to allow image width to exceed the width of the div that it is in

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is `1140px` wide and am image sitting within it that I need to fit the screen size, Is it possible to make the image width size larger than the div width that it is sitting in?

```
<div className="row" style="width: 1140px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
    <img className="aimg" src="~/images/background.gif" style="height: 325px" />
</div>
```

CSS as follows:

```
.aimg {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

As it stands, the div width is limiting the image from fitting the screen width

Comment: Have you tried `position: absolute`?

Comment: The width of the img is not limited by the containing div. you can check this fiddle out : http://jsfiddle.net/s6davtkb/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `position: absolute; width: 100vw; height: 100vh;` to you `img` styles and it should work :)

"`vw`" stands for viewWidth and "`vh`", accordingly, for viewHeight.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

**Below codepen is based on:**

https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

**Codepen itself:**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzawqv

Comment: how would I now get the image to start from the left of the screen as it now begins from the position of the div

Comment: your answer works fine Sir, I just added a left: 0; to image tag and all works fine

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

you need css classes for container and image, the following example suppose to the div width is fixed width and set with 480px.

```
.div_image {    
    max-height:480px;
    height: 480px;
}

.div_image img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You do not need a "css class" to style an element.